# How to set features Types in Mapbox Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

Using Mapbox Swift to list nearby points of interest is returning one result by default. Increasing the `limit` to 10 throws the following error:

> limit must be combined with a single type parameter when reverse geocoding

This can be solved by passing the types of features as `POI`.

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/55.274111,25.197139.json?
access_token=pk..&limit=10&types=poi'
```

How to set the `types` in Mapbox Swift?  There is no such property in `ReverseGeocodeOptions` class.

```
let options = ReverseGeocodeOptions(coordinate: 
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.733, longitude: -73.989))

let task = geocoder.geocode(options) { (placemarks, attribution, error) in
    guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else {
        return
    }

    print(placemark.imageName ?? "")
        // telephone
    print(placemark.genres?.joined(separator: ", ") ?? "")
        // computer, electronic
    print(placemark.administrativeRegion?.name ?? "")
        // New York
    print(placemark.administrativeRegion?.code ?? "")
        // US-NY 
}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: I updated the question with sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By searching the [MapboxGeocoder.swift](https://github.com/mapbox/MapboxGeocoder.swift) project I found the [list of types](https://github.com/mapbox/MapboxGeocoder.swift/blob/master/MapboxGeocoder/MBPlacemarkScope.swift). They are:

- "country"
- "region"
- "district"
- "postcode"
- "place"
- "locality"
- "neighborhood"
- "address"
- "poi.landmark"
- "poi"

**UPDATE**

In order to set the option types for `ReverseGeocodeOptions`, set the `allowedScopes` property.

```
let geocodeOptions = ReverseGeocodeOptions(coordinate: coordinate)
geocodeOptions.allowedScopes = .pointOfInterest
```

Note that `allowedScopes` is a set of types, so you can create multiple types, e.g.

```
geocodeOptions.allowedScopes = [.pointOfInterest, .landmark]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I set the types of the feature in the `ReverseGeocodeOptions`?